# Ajax request in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I want to send an AJAX request in WordPress which tracks my clicks. So far, I have added this in my functions file:

```
add_action('init', 'my_script_enqueuer');

  function my_script_enqueuer() {
    wp_register_script("history_script", get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/history_script.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('history_script', 'myAjax', array('ajaxurl' => get_template_directory_uri().'/functions.php'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('history_script');
  }

  add_action("wp_ajax_history_trace", "history_trace");

  function history_trace() {
      echo 'fasfasgasgas'; die;
}
```

And this in my js file :

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

   jQuery("#searchsubmit").click( function() { 
      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {action: "history_trace"},
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
               alert('success')
            }
            else {
               alert("false")
            }
         }
      })   

   })

})
```

But in my console, the request appears in red, and there is no response. Please Help!

Comment: Make sure that `myAjax.ajaxurl` is using the same protocol and domain as the page with the JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: the request appears in red means you are getting response code 500. probably PHP syntax error. Set WP_DEBUG to TRUE to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, use the following url to process AJAX requests:

`array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )`

It's also important to localize a script **after** it has been enqueued.